# how to make non root user as sudo user in docker alpine image?

Tags: docker, containers, sudo, alpine-linux, sudoers

I am trying build cassandra docker image using alpine based os. on the container run process i am getting permission related issue, as i am running as cassandra user. i am unable to run sudo and switch my user cassandra as sudo user. below is my sample docker file, shows only sudo user related logic--

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache update \
    && apk --no-cache add sudo
copy run.sh /usr/local/
RUN addgroup -S cassandra && adduser -S cassandra -G cassandra
RUN chown -R cassandra:cassandra /home/cassandra/
RUN echo 'cassandra  ALL=(ALL) /bin/su' >>  /etc/sudoers
USER cassandra
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh","/usr/local/run.sh"]
```

after login to container i am unable to perform any sudo related task.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/mhart/alpine-node/issues/48

Answer (score 25):

First thing, you do not need to assign root permission to newly created user, which kill purpose of the user.

So you do not need to change user to `root` user, you can run command in the running container with `root` user.

```
docker exec -it --user root mycontainer sh
```

or in Dockerfile

```
USER root
# Run root operation here
# Change user back to cassandra
USER cassandra
```

Btw you can create root user using below commands

Dockerfile

```
RUN adduser -D $USER && mkdir -p /etc/sudoers.d \
        && echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/$USER \
        && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USER
USER $USER
WORKDIR $HOME
RUN whoami
RUN sudo whoami
```

Build Output

```
Step 9/11 : RUN whoami
 ---> Running in d52065213d2d
default
Removing intermediate container d52065213d2d
 ---> c1b526ea8342
Step 10/11 : RUN sudo whoami
 ---> Running in 5f4ddd11a5f2
root
```

Comment: Sometimes it is needed to create a user with high privileges for a tool that forcibly doesn't work under the root user.